# Fastlane, iOS Provisioning Profiles & Push Notification permissions (by example)

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, apple-developer

I am trying to get Fastlane to take the source code for my iOS app and build/codesign it into an archive/IPA file. Here is my `Fastfile`:

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  lane :staging do
    puts "iOS staging build"
    clean_build_artifacts
    disable_automatic_code_signing(path: "./ios/myappmobile.xcodeproj")
    build_app(
      scheme: "myappmobile",
      project: "./ios/myappmobile.xcodeproj",
      export_options: {
        signingStyle: "manual",
        provisioningProfiles: {
          "com.myapp" => "/Users/myuser/workspace/myapp/myappprovisioningprofile.mobileprovision"
        }
      },
      clean: true
    )
  end
end
```

It's important to note that `/Users/myuser/workspace/myapp/myappprovisioningprofile.mobileprovision` is a valid file path/location and is where I've downloaded my Provisioning Profile file to.

When I run `fastlane ios staging` I get the following error:

```
error: "myappmobile" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'myappmobile' from project 'myappmobile')
```

When I was creating my App and all relevant resources (Certificate, Provisioning Profile, etc.) I remember selecting a checkbox stating that I would like to give my app Push Notification capabilities.

So my first assumption was that Fastlane was finding my Provisioning Profile file (`myappprovisioningprofile.mobileprovision`) and perhaps something inside of it hadn't been configured correctly. But I get the same error even if I change the `provisioningProfiles` value from:

```
provisioningProfiles: {
  "com.myapp" => "/Users/myuser/workspace/myapp/myappprovisioningprofile.mobileprovision"
}
```

to gibberish:

```
provisioningProfiles: {
  "com.myapp" => "flim-flam-fizz-buzz"
}
```

**What is going on here?!** Why isn't Fastlane able to find my provisioning profile file (does it need to be a relative path for some reason?!). But then the craziest thing is: it knows that the app requires Push Notifications but without being able to read/parse the Provisioning Profile, so how does it know that Push Notifications are a requirement?!

#### Update

After re-configuring my `build_app` command with some recommended settings, I have gotten past the Push Notifications problem but am now running into this:

```
 error: No signing certificate "iOS Distribution" found: No "iOS Distribution" signing certificate matching team ID "<redacted>" with a private key was found. (in target 'myappmobile' from project 'myappmobile')
```

I have a distribution certificate (`ios_distribution.cer`) that I created off of the Apple Developer console (web) and downloaded. How can I configure Fastlane to "see" (or use) this certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to enter the path, just name of your profile as it called in your apple account, here is the part of my fastfile

```
 export_options: {
        "signingStyle" => "manual", 
    provisioningProfiles: {
            "com.YOUR_APP.application" => "Distribution",
        "com.YOUR_APP.application.AB24Intents" => "AB24Intents",
        "com.YOUR_APP.application.ABRPWidget" => "ABRPWidget"
                
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Alexandr Kolesnik. Please see my update above, your recommended changes are causing another error to rear its head (this time, certificate based), do you know why I might be seeing this, and more importantly, what the fix/solution is? Thanks again!

Comment: As I see, your cert, you add to the keychain doesn't have a private key. Have you installed your profiles in xcode?

Comment: I installed the Profile in XCode but I believe I forgot to install the certificate (after I downloaded it) locally on my Mac. Would that cause this error?

Comment: I hope it will fix an issue, why don't you use Automatic settings, it is much easier

Comment: I don't believe I can use automatic settings from a CI/CD server. Automatic settings work great for local development, but eventually I need my CI server building + codesigning the code, and producing an archive file that I can upload to either TestFlight or the App Store. But @Alexandr Kolesnik please let me know if that's incorrect!

Comment: If your settings in xcode are Automatic, you don't need manual options in your script